# Most equivalent factors of a number

Tags: c++, math

Given a number 'n', which is a power-of-2, how can I efficiently find the 2 factors which are most equivalent to eachother? In other words, if I have a linear array and want to map it to 2D, how can I find the 2D dimensions that are the most equal (image dimensions most close to a square)?

Gotta be some kind of bitwise operation to make this fast, rather than looping over factors.

Comment: `n` is representable as `2^k` (since you say it's a power of 2). If `k` is even, then `n == 2^(k/2) * 2^(k/2)` (e.g. `16==4*4`). If `k` is odd, then the closest you can get is `n == 2^((k-1)/2) * 2^((k+1)/2)` (e.g. `8==2*4`)

Comment: You are absolutely right in your suspicions. Now, you just need to think what "2 to the nth" power means, mathematically, and given the `n`, how to find a number that when multiplied by itself results in this "2^n". Free clue: this is easy when `n` is even.

Comment: Fantastic! Please post as answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`n` is representable as `2^k` (since you say it's a power of 2). If `k` is even, then `n == 2^(k/2) * 2^(k/2)` (e.g. `16==4*4`). If `k` is odd, then the closest you can get is `n == 2^((k-1)/2) * 2^((k+1)/2)` (e.g. `8==2*4`)